# SIGN_IN_REQUIRED error in google play game services sample app

Tags: android, google-play-games

I know there was alot of problems regarding the signing in for TypeANumber app in the console, but none of them solved my problem.

it is the 4th time i redo everything and read every step carefully but still cant make it to work.

the package name is the same in the app, the console and the google api console
same goes for the sha1 sertificate.

I even checked the exported apk to see it' sha1 as said in the Troubleshooting section. (did all of the troubleshooting)

the testing access is my only gmail account that i use for the console and the one i have in my android device.

Also multiplayer settings and anti piracy is turned off

I even saw **"Top 7 Google Play game services setup mistakes "** talk they did about it few weeks ago, but still it doesn't work!

I have no idea what could be the problem. done the setup prosses over and over again so many times that im lost. Thanks.

Note this is for the sample app **TypeANumber**

Could there be other problems with this api that will give this error? maybe some flags in my google+ account or console account for some reason?

full log:

```
06-28 16:41:22.783: D/dalvikvm(32585): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-28 16:41:22.943: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onCreate: creating GamesClient
06-28 16:41:22.943: I/dalvikvm(32585): Could not find method android.view.View.getDisplay, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b.b
06-28 16:41:22.943: W/dalvikvm(32585): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3169: Landroid/view/View;.getDisplay ()Landroid/view/Display;
06-28 16:41:22.943: D/dalvikvm(32585): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
06-28 16:41:22.943: I/dalvikvm(32585): Could not find method android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b.a
06-28 16:41:22.943: W/dalvikvm(32585): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3280: Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver;.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener (Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener;)V
06-28 16:41:22.943: D/dalvikvm(32585): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002f
06-28 16:41:22.948: W/PopupManager(32585): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
06-28 16:41:23.123: D/dalvikvm(32585): GC_CONCURRENT freed 194K, 4% free 9433K/9735K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-28 16:41:23.138: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onStart.
06-28 16:41:23.138: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onStart: connecting clients.
06-28 16:41:23.158: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): Connecting GamesClient.
06-28 16:41:23.228: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onConnectionFailed: result 4
06-28 16:41:23.228: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onConnectionFailed: since user didn't initiate sign-in, failing now.
06-28 16:41:23.243: D/dalvikvm(32585): GC_CONCURRENT freed 87K, 3% free 9757K/9991K, paused 1ms+2ms
06-28 16:41:23.298: D/CLIPBOARD(32585): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-28 16:41:42.938: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
06-28 16:41:42.938: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
06-28 16:41:43.023: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{415973a0: android.os.BinderProxy@415556a0}}
06-28 16:41:43.023: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): result has resolution. Starting it.
06-28 16:41:43.108: D/CLIPBOARD(32585): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-28 16:41:45.503: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onActivityResult, req 9001 response 10002
06-28 16:41:45.503: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): responseCode != RESULT_OK, so not reconnecting.
06-28 16:41:45.503: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): giveUp: giving up on connection. Status code: 4
06-28 16:41:45.503: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): Making error dialog for error: 4
06-28 16:41:51.873: D/dalvikvm(32585): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-28 16:42:06.733: D/CLIPBOARD(32585): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-28 16:42:07.248: D/BaseGameActivity(32585): onStop: disconnecting clients.
```

EDIT:
When i was trying to set BaseGameUtil as a lib for a **new project** i'v got an error saying:
    Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

it says something about different SHA1 for those two android-support-v4.jar, could this couse the error in the TypeANumber application?

EDIT2:
Do you have to match the name of your app in the console to the one in the manifest file aswell?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you resolve this problem first :

> EDIT2: When i was trying to set BaseGameUtil as a lib for a new
>   project i'v got an error saying: Found 2 versions of
>   android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list
>   it says something about different SHA1 for those two
>   android-support-v4.jar, could this couse the error in the TypeANumber
>   application?

This issue is well-documented on Stack Overflow and there are various approaches that you can take. When I encountered this, I first ensured that the copy that was contained in my own project was the correct version for me (I use the ActionBar Sherlock version) and I then removed the copy of the Support Library from BaseGameUtils.  If you are unsure which version of the Support library to keep then I suggest that you should just copy the version from BaseGameUtils into your project.

When you have resolved this issue and if you still have problems, I suggest you open another question. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for replay, this problem was when i created a new project, not in the tTypeANumber project, i didn't add any other libs to it besides the BaseGameUtil, maybe also the google play services lib.

Why should i start a new question? i dont know all the publishing rules here, can you post the same question again?

I will try to remove that lib from the new test project i created and see, but could maybe one of my accounts has some kind of a flag or something that prompt that error? (google+ or my consule account?)

Comment: OK I have edited my reply to reflect the fact that your error is in your own project not TypeANumber. In my experience, I get better responses on Stack Overflow when I ask very specific questions. The SHA1 problem is a very well-defined problem with a very clear error message which I suggest you address before you attempt to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'v edited my question to make it cleared i hope.